# Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 644754-by-1

Tags: matlab

Estoy tratando de añadir dos arreglos en uno pero que el segundo arreglo este en la segunda columna pero me genera este error.

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 644754-by-1.

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?.

```
%Leer el formato y señal de audio.
[y,Fs] = audioread('FormatoUSB.wav');
%Mostrar información completa del audio
info = audioinfo('FormatoUSB.wav')
%Obtención de info de cada canal
audio_L = y(:,1);
audio_R = y(:,2); 
%Filtrado de señal
audio_l= reshape(audio_L,1,644754);
audio_r= reshape(audio_R,1,644754);
HRIR_l = hrir_l(:,1,1);
HRIR_r = hrir_r(:,2,1);
Hrir_L = reshape(HRIR_l,1,25);
Hrir_R = reshape(HRIR_r,1,25);
Z_l = zeros(1,644729);
Z_r = zeros(1,644729);
Filtro_L = [Hrir_L Z_l];
Filtro_R = [Hrir_R Z_r];
audioHRIR_L = 0.5* filter(Filtro_L,1,audio_l);
audioHRIR_R = 0.5* filter(Filtro_R,1,audio_r);
canal_L = reshape(audioHRIR_L,644754,1);
canal_R = reshape(audioHRIR_R,644754,1);
y1(1,1) = canal_L;
y1 (2,1) = canal_R;
%Crear el nuevo tipo de audio
%filename = 'FORMATO_HRIR.wav';
%audiowrite(filename,y1,Fs);
%clear y Fs
```

Esto lo hago por después necesito una información para agregarla al audio que quiero crear.

Comment: y en qué línea falla? Ya verificaste que tu audio sea realmente estéreo?

Comment: y1(1,1) = canal_L;
y1 (2,1) = canal_R;

Creo que es en esta linea ya que, solo me esta agregando un arreglo a la fila 2 y en la otra no se esta agregando nada, si el audio claramente es estéreo.

Comment: Intenta agregarle línea por línea de manera interactiva para que estés seguro

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje es claro: Lo que esta en la derecha no es del mismo tamano que lo que esta en la izquierda. No puedes meter en una variable de un solo numero (`y1(1,1)`) algo que es mas grande que un solo numero (`canal_L`, que es 644754x1).

Como solucionarlo? Asegurate de usas indices del tamano adecuado. En MATLAB puedes usar `:` para decir "todos los indices", asi que el codigo siguiente

```
y1(1,:) = canal_L;
y1 (2,:) = canal_R;
```

Dice, "en y1, la primera fila, todas las columnas, rellenalas con `canal_L`". Lo mismo con `canal_R`